# Fomatting from a list to a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, forex

Disclaimer: Beginner

I have a list of currency pairs like below:

```
  pair_list = ["AUD/CAD","CAD/SEK","CHF/DKK"]
```

I am trying to map each pair to a function like below:

```
AUD_CAD, metadata_AUD_CAD = fx.get_currency_exchange_daily(from_symbol='AUD',to_symbol='CAD', outputsize="full")
```

I've tried a few solutions to get this to work but no success so far, I know the solution is simple but I've not found it yet. In the meantime, does anyone know how I would go about getting this?

Comment: Perhaps an array of values is not ideal. Have you considered an array of dicts with key/value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = {}
for pair in pair_list:
    (from, to) = pair.split('/')
    result[pair] = fx.get_currency_exchange_daily(from_symbol=from, to_symbol=to, outputsize="full")
```